# I'm trying to use `backoff` and `map_err`, what is the correct way for `Transient` errors

Tags: rust

I am trying to handle errors in a way that looks like this:

[image]

The first `ConnectionLost` case seems to be fine, but for the other case I'm getting the following `cargo check` errors:

```
Expected function, found `backoff::Error::Transient` [E0618]
This function takes 2 parameters but 1 parameter was supplied [E0061]
```

I was under the impression that if I want to I can only supply one argument to `Transient`.
I am using the latest version of `backoff = 0.4.0`.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors, post the error output of `cargo check` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want function [`backoff::Error::transient`](https://docs.rs/backoff/0.4.0/backoff/enum.Error.html#method.transient) instead of the variant [`Transient`](https://docs.rs/backoff/0.4.0/backoff/enum.Error.html#variant.Transient). The variant changed in the 0.4.0 version.

Comment: But then they decided to keep `Permanent` with a capital P!!

Comment: You can use [`backoff::Error::permanent`](https://docs.rs/backoff/0.4.0/backoff/enum.Error.html#method.permanent) too